# On 8088/86, does a shift/rotate by CL alter the value in CL?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

In the iAP88/86 documentation, the timing information for the shifts and rotates depends on the shift count in CL (p2-64). This seems to imply that it's looping over the count in CL, doing that many single-bit shifts.

So my question is, does CL still have the same value after the rotate/shift completes, or does the operation count it down, similar to how the LOOP instruction behaves?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I'm writing an 8088/8086 emulator, and I don't have original hardware to test on at the moment.

Comment: would think it would need to be still compatible with todays x86, and there are other emulators, what do they do with this instruction?

Comment: Good point about backward compatibility. I was leaning towards not altering CL, since I get the feeling Intel would have documented it otherwise, but unless someone here has a spec or some hardware that settles the matter, I guess I'll have to wait until I can lay hands on a 5150 PC or something else with the right chip in it.

Comment: Although I have thought about it recently I no longer have any 8088/86 chips either to just try,  I would start with a current x86 see what it does and assume that is safe...until you have access or proof otherwise..someone with an actual legacy chip...note that that may still not settle it as various steppings may behave differently although we would expect to see an errata if that were the case.

Comment: the visual 6502 folks might eventually get around to dissecting and reverse engineering one as well...I wouldnt wait for that though.

Comment: It doesn't modify `CL`. This would have been documented by *somebody*, even if not Intel themselves. I've never seen *anything* about this, either in books or in code. So you can safely assume that it does not. I do have an IBM 5150 in storage, though, so if you need someone to check, you can bounty this question. :-)

Comment: Or, there is Andrew's [XT Server](http://www.reenigne.org/xtserver/). I believe he's also written ([was working on?](http://www.reenigne.org/blog/i-bought-an-xt/)) a cycle-exact 8088 emulator. I haven't looked into it any further, but [he has a GitHub account](https://github.com/reenigne/reenigne/tree/master/8088).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Intel 8088, shift or rotate by a value in CL leaves CL unchanged. This is true for these instructions: `RCL RCR ROL ROR SAL SAR SHL SHR`

Semantics for these instructions on the Intel 8088 are specified in the [iAPX 88 Book from July 1981](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/www.bitsavers.org/pdf/intel/8086/210200_iAPX88_Book_1981.pdf).

Taking ROL for exposition, syntax is: `ROL destination,count`

The encoding specification establishes the value of the symbol `COUNT` used in the semantics spec. For the relevant instruction form the value of CL is assigned to the symbol:

```
if v = 0 then COUNT = 1
else COUNT = (CL)
```

The semantics spec indicates the value of the symbol COUNT is assigned to a temporary variable. The register CL is never changed.

```
(temp) ← COUNT
do while (temp) ≠ 0
  (CF) ← high-order bit of (EA)
  (EA) ← (EA) * 2 + (CF)
  (temp) ← (temp)-1
if COUNT = 1 then
  if high-order bit of (EA) ≠ (CF)
    then (OF) ← 1
  else (OF) ← 0
else (OF) undefined
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 3):

No. Shift/rotate operations do not alter `cl`. You can clearly see this from Intel's pseudo code:

```
IF 64-Bit Mode and using REX.W
  THEN
    countMASK ← 3FH;
  ELSE
    countMASK ← 1FH;
  FI

  tempCOUNT ← (COUNT AND countMASK);
  tempDEST ← DEST;
  WHILE (tempCOUNT ≠ 0)
  DO
      IF instruction is SAL or SHL
        THEN
          CF ← MSB(DEST);
        ELSE (* Instruction is SAR or SHR *)
          CF ← LSB(DEST);
      FI;
      IF instruction is SAL or SHL
        THEN
          DEST ← DEST ∗ 2;
        ELSE
          IF instruction is SAR
            THEN
              DEST ← DEST / 2; (* Signed divide, rounding toward negative infinity *)
            ELSE (* Instruction is SHR *)
              DEST ← DEST / 2 ; (* Unsigned divide *)
          FI;
      FI;
      tempCOUNT ← tempCOUNT – 1;
  OD;

(* Determine overflow for the various instructions *)
IF (COUNT and countMASK) = 1
  THEN
    IF instruction is SAL or SHL
      THEN
        OF ← MSB(DEST) XOR CF;
      ELSE
        IF instruction is SAR
          THEN
            OF ← 0;
          ELSE (* Instruction is SHR *)
            OF ← MSB(tempDEST);
        FI;
    FI;
  ELSE IF (COUNT AND countMASK) = 0
      THEN
        All flags unchanged;
      ELSE (* COUNT not 1 or 0 *)
        OF ← undefined;
    FI;
FI;
```

As you can clearly see, `CL` is assigned to `tempCOUNT` before being looped, so `CL` stays unchanged.

Note that the original 8086 doesn't mask the shift count which yields slightly different results in case the shift count is a multiple of the register size.

In general, I recommend you to confer the Intel manuals for your emulators. They specify to great detail how every single instruction is supposed to work.

Comment: Can you give me a citation for that excerpt please? I've been using iAPX86,88 User's Manual, August 1981, order # 210201-001, and I don't think it has the detailed pseudocode for the ops in it. Its descriptions are mostly in plain english with a couple of flowcharts here and there.

Comment: @JamesGeorgas This is from the most recent copy of the Intel manuals. You can find them on [Intel's web page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).

Comment: does the most recent copy of the manuals state compatibility back to the original 8088/86?

Comment: @old_timer Not completely, but they do a better job than the original manuals do.

Comment: @old_timer I would say “mostly.” They do mention all quirks I know, but it is possible that they don't mention everything.